# Resetting with move constructor

Tags: c++11

I was reading about the move constructor in an attempt to learn C++11 and it states that

> The move constructor resets the source pointer rhs.data_. This way,
>   when the temporary is destroyed, delete[] will be harmlessly applied
>   to a null pointer.

Now the author does something like this

```
MemoryPage(MemoryPage&& other): size(0), buf(nullptr)
{
   // pilfer other’s resource
   size=other.size;
   buf=other.buf;
   // reset other
   other.size=0;
   other.buf=nullptr;
}
```

My question is if other.buf is actually a pointer isn't it suppose to be

```
delete other.buf;
```

why are we simply assigning nullptr to it during resetting ? Wont it end up to be a memory leak ?

Comment: the move ctor has nothing to do with destroying or deallocating anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is if `other.buf` is actually a pointer isn't it suppose to be
>
> ```
> delete other.buf;
> ```

no, because a line earlier you copied the pointer to `this->buf`:

> ```
> buf=other.buf;
> ```

move constructor is taking any memory buffers from `other` object, and is making sure `other` will safely be destroyed.

Here is nice description of what move constructor is actually doing:

> Rvalue references, aka "move construction/assignment," are a useful
>   way to express that you’re constructing or assigning from an object
>   that will no longer be used for anything else — including, for
>   example, a temporary object — and so you can often get a decent
>   performance boost by simply stealing the guts of the other object
>   instead of making a potentially expensive deep copy.

http://herbsutter.com/2007/05/10/trip-report-april-2007-iso-c-standards-meeting/

so this line:

```
buf=other.buf;
```

is actually "stealing the guts of the other object." The other object no longer needs them, it will soon vanish.